# Rails gsub for russian symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gsub, cyrillic

In my rails app i need to format my string so that it consist only letters, without symbols. But main trouble is that string is in russian language, so how do it? For rnglish and letters and digits i do that:

```
ArtLookup.get_analog(@articles.ART_ARTICLE_NR.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ''))
```

But how to do it for russian alphabet? (first is А, last is Я). Only letters, and delete spaces?

Answer (score 7):

Use `\p{Cyrillic}`, which matches any cyrillic character.

Example:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > s = "helloЯ"
 => "helloЯ" 
1.9.3p194 :002 > s.gsub(/\p{Cyrillic}/, '')
 => "hello"
```

More info on special characters handling in Ruby: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html

**Edited Answer:**

If you want only a subset of the cyrillic alphabet, I'm afraid you have to build your own set.

For this, you can try to use a range: `/[а-я]+/i`, which should work. If it doesn't, just specify your alphabet explicitely: `/[абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя]+/i`

Comment: hm but how to say him only letters?

Comment: You might want to edit your initial post with the errors you're having in order for us to help you.